# Clip and ship by a queried layer extent and by user defined extent

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, data, select

I am trying add a functionality to the [clip and ship script](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/gp_clipasync.html). I would also like the users to extract data by the extent of a queried feature layer. For instance, if County = "Alameda" then extract data that falls only within the Alameda county extent. Else, allow the users to hand draw an selection area. If any of have clues or ideas I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool idea.

Accomplishing this will take a couple of steps.

I will say I have not tested ANY of the code in this answer.  It is possible for errors or syntax issues, but the general idea is there.

Here is how you could grab the county extent.

```
var county = document.getElementById("sel_county").value;  //Your county select object
var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://www.example.com/Counties/0");  //Your county feature service
var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.outFields = ["COUNTY_NAME"];  //Your county name field in your feature service
query.where = "COUNTY_NAME = " + county;  
queryTask.execute(query, function(featureSet){    //If you want a result handler function, just replace that here
     var AOI = featureSet.features[0].geometry.toJSON(); //This is designed to get the FIRST feature graphic as a JSON in the return because I am assuming you only have one county with that name
});
```

For users to draw an extent, I recommend taking a look at the [drawing tool](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/toolbar_draw.html).  The extent shape is activated via:

```
toolbar.activate(Draw["EXTENT"]);
```

The complete handler for drawing the extent can be handled as an event, and the geometry can be returned.  Like in the drawing example I linked the addToMap(evt) function could be used to grab the geometry.  Something like this in that function would setup the same extent I showed earlier:

```
var AOI = evt.geometry.toJSON();  //Since the geometry started as an extent and not a polygon, we do not need to get the extent again
```

AOI stands for Area of Interest - this matches the parameter for the Geometry object of the clip and ship.

Then set the Area of Interest param to your AOI JSON object.

Good luck!

Comment: That is extremely helpful. This is will help greatly what I am trying to achieve! I knew I needed to use the "featureSet" function at some point but had no clue how and where. Thank you much for your help. I am hoping to get  back tomorrow on this site and post a working solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok. I am a bit too new to JS API. I applied the script you wrote to the clip and ship script here: http://jsbin.com/yayeq/1/edit but none of my testing conditions work, I am not sure why. Thank you. Alex